# What is your view on the [open-ended] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently made a new tag called [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) which seems to work fine, but out of curiosity, what's the community's view on it?

[open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended)

> Used when the tagged puzzle is open ended to all solvers and could be "bested" at any point, if a given solver has a better solution that fulfills the askers requirements.

**I'd especially like to hear from active members and moderators!**

Comment: The [laser puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/can-you-solve-those-laser-puzzles-puzzles-created-by-the-community) seems really out of place there...

Comment: @Sp3000 perhaps it is...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the genre itself (as long as questions are still of high quality, of course), but the tag seems to be somewhat of a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). It doesn't describe the *content* of the question; it describes the question itself.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I'm very glad to see that moderators saying "I don't see anything wrong with the genre itself (as long as questions are still of high quality, of course)" is acceptable. I've been asking you three to make such a statement about challenge questions (and particularly riddles) for DAYS, but keep getting replies like 'it wouldn't be appropriate' or 'that's for the community to decide, not the moderators'. Thank you for setting a precedent! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor "[I'm personally content with challenges on Puzzling](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1682/4)" by Emrakul almost a week ago.

Comment: I'm a little more skeptical than doorknob about the acceptability of truly open-ended questions. But I don't think all those questions currently tagged with open-ended are truly open-ended.

Comment: @Kevin Just because I tagged them don't make them any less of an example. Just look at the description.

Comment: @warspyking The implication was that there are questions matching your use of the tag that are lower quality but not tagged.

Comment: @Kevin I only picked recent ones, I didn't have time to go back to the beginning if the site or anything...

Comment: @Kevin - That was Emrakul. What about you and Doorknob?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I originally posted this comment:

> I don't see anything wrong with the genre itself (as long as questions are still of high quality, of course), but the tag seems to be somewhat of a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). It doesn't describe the *content* of the question; it describes the question itself.

After your edit, though, you've added this definition:

> Used when the tagged puzzle is open ended to all solvers and could be "bested" at any point, if a given solver has a better solution that fulfills the askers requirements.

In that case, what's the point of even having the tag in the first place? Shouldn't it be applied to *all questions on the site*? Why would you *not* accept a better answer? (Let's put aside the fact that it's most certainly a meta tag at this point, which is grounds for burnination.)

Comment: the idea is that it's open for a competition to find the best answer.

Comment: @warspyking As opposed to "I don't want any more answers even if they're better so go away"?

Comment: I mean that the idea is for the solvers to compete to find better and better answers, other than "that question has an answer and it's really good, why waste time solving again?" The tag tells people, the real puzzle, is beating another's answer.

Comment: I think a better way to express it is that it's not a puzzle that becomes "solved" -- you just find the best-scoring answer you can.

Comment: @xnor Yea, like that.

Comment: Isn't "riddle" a meta-tag too?

Comment: @warspyking [tag:riddle] describes the content of the question, rather than some meta-level aspect about the question itself. As a result, it isn't a meta-tag. The important post to read is [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @Emrakul doesn't "*riddle*" describe that it's a riddle, describing the question, not the content..?

Answer (score 1):

Just some random thoughts: I think that the open-ended tag is *useless* for ordinary puzzles for the reasons given by Doorknob (hence my UP vote for his answer). However, I think it has (limited) use for puzzles like the [laser puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/can-you-solve-those-laser-puzzles-puzzles-created-by-the-community), where the open-ended-ness is not given by the fact that a 'better' answer can be found, but that each answer *creates a new puzzle*.

But I do have a big problem with this tag: The [laser puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/can-you-solve-those-laser-puzzles-puzzles-created-by-the-community) is the single one puzzle where I find it appropriate, and I'm not sure we would like to invite more puzzles of that kind.

This is not in anyway a down-valuing of the [laser puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/can-you-solve-those-laser-puzzles-puzzles-created-by-the-community) itself (I was the first to pick it up to get it rolling.), but it seemed to be or *become* **more a game than a puzzle**, and I really think this might be the point where we draw the line between "good for (Puzzling) SE" and "not suitable for (Puzzling) SE" - simply because the very nature of it contradicts the way this site has been build.

Personally, I think we should kill the tag to avoid inviting these *type* of questions.
( I think the *laser puzzle* could have fit better as *either* a request to create the most-interesting/difficult puzzle with the tool, *or* as presenting one or two very interesting puzzles with it. Both would have given it a permanent touch with the possibility to "accept & close" it. (Not as in VTC but as in closed=finished).